# How to shorten a UUID to a given length?

Tags: ruby, uuid

I'd like to use a UUID for database records but if I'm using it for the URL I'd like it to be 5 to 8 characters.

I know I need to use `SecureRandom` and `base64`, but how do I specify the length I need?

Answer (score 18):

You can't get a real UUID down to 5-8 characters, as another answer points out, but you can shorten them somewhat.  UUIDs are 128-bit integers which works out to 32 hex digits.  You can easily store 6 bits per character and cut the length down to 22 characters, which is what base 64 encoding is.  Standard base 64 encoding uses upper and lower case letters, digits, and "+" and "/" to finish it out.  If you replace "+" and "/" with "-" and "_" you will end up with a string that doesn't have to be url encoded.  You can do it like this (using UUIDTools to create the UUID):

```
uuid = UUIDTools::UUID.random_create
str = [uuid.raw].pack('m*').tr('+/','-_').slice(0..21)
```

To get your value back out:

```
(str + "==\n").tr('-_','+/').unpack('m*').first if str =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{22}$/
```

That's assuming the UUID can be put into a raw format where it's a string of 16 8-bit characters.  Here's an irb session showing a real example:

```
2.1.1 :016 > uuid=UUIDTools::UUID.random_create
 => #<UUID:0x83f1e98c UUID:20d07b6c-52af-4e53-afea-6b3ad0d0c627> 
2.1.1 :017 > uuid.raw
 => " \xD0{lR\xAFNS\xAF\xEAk:\xD0\xD0\xC6'" 
2.1.1 :018 > str = [uuid.raw].pack('m*').tr('+/','-_').slice(0..21)
 => "INB7bFKvTlOv6ms60NDGJw" 
2.1.1 :019 > uuid2 =  (str + "==\n").tr('-_','+/').unpack('m*').first
 => " \xD0{lR\xAFNS\xAF\xEAk:\xD0\xD0\xC6'" 
2.1.1 :022 > UUIDTools::UUID.parse_raw(uuid2)
 => #<UUID:0x849e6b44 UUID:20d07b6c-52af-4e53-afea-6b3ad0d0c627>
```

I use this method on various web sites where I typically use Postgres to generate UUIDs as primary keys for tables and pass them as ids.  It doesn't save a lot of space but it does make some URLs fit on one 80 character line where a full UUID in standard format wouldn't.  With dashes, a standard UUID is 36 characters so 22 is about 2/3 the size.

Comment: Make sure you also look below at Luc Boissaye's answer.

Answer (score 10):

I created two single line function based on Michael Chaney

```
def encode(uuid)     
  [uuid.tr('-', '').scan(/../).map(&:hex).pack('c*')].pack('m*').tr('+/', '-_').slice(0..21)                                                   
end
def decode(short_id)
 (short_id.tr('-_', '+/') + '==').unpack('m0').first.unpack('H8H4H4H4H12').join('-')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
end

uuid = "355bf501-ffea-4f5a-a9e2-16074de6fcf2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
=> "355bf501-ffea-4f5a-a9e2-16074de6fcf2"                                                                                                                                                                          
encode(uuid)      
=> "NVv1Af_qT1qp4hYHTeb88g"        
decode(_)         
=> "355bf501-ffea-4f5a-a9e2-16074de6fcf2
```

Comment: Would there be an issue if I stored shortened UUIDs in my Postgres database?

Comment: Hi @Qasim, you can but then I think you will have to store it as string and then not be as performant as with postgresql native uuid type.

Answer (score 2):

I use an alphabet of 62 (Base62) characters, because I don't want `-` and `_` in my shortened UUIDs. The UUID shortener shortens a 36 long UUID to a 22 character long string. I use this UUID shortener in Rails. Change the alphabet to your needs.

Here my UUID shortener:

## Code

```
# lib/uuid_shortener.rb
module UuidShortener
  ALPHABET = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
  ALPHABET_HASH = ALPHABET.each_char.with_index.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = v; }
  BASE = ALPHABET.length

  class << self
    def shorten(uuid)
      num = uuid.tr('-', '').to_i(16)
      return '0' if num.zero?
      return nil if num.negative?

      str = ''
      while num.positive?
        str = ALPHABET[num % BASE] + str
        num /= BASE
      end
      str
    end

    def expand(suid)
      num = i = 0
      len = suid.length - 1
      while i < suid.length
        pow = BASE**(len - i)
        num += ALPHABET_HASH[suid[i]] * pow
        i += 1
      end
      num.to_s(16).rjust(32, '0').unpack('A8A4A4A4A12').join('-')
    end
  end
end
```

## Usage

1. Generate an UUID

```
> uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
> uuid 
=> "2ff7b050-2a37-4d52-a8f0-76cffccbefe3"
```

2. Short UUID

```
> suid = UuidShortener.shorten(uuid)
> suid
=> "1svPFI0god7vT7MNxKIrfR"
```

3. Expand SUID

```
> UuidShortener.expand(suid)
=> "2ff7b050-2a37-4d52-a8f0-76cffccbefe3"
```