# How can I create numbered (random) urls for my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'd like my URLS to be a random mix of characters (like YouTube does at the end of video URLS)

Is there a gem to do this?  Can I link my UUIDs to each post so that a random mix of numbers is created?

Any advice would be appreciated - been looking for some sort of solution for days (well at this rate, nights)!

Answer (score 2):

You can use UUIDs if you wish.  I use postgres as my database and it has a UUID datatype now that can be used as the primary key for a database table rather easily.  I also use code to "compress" the UUID down to 22 characters (see [How can I shorten a UUID to a specific length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615900/how-can-i-shorten-uuid-in-rails/26617391#26617391) for information) and then use that as the id.  It takes little code to accomplish this.

It's also possible to just use plain random strings of characters using SecureRandom (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) if you want, there are various ways of doing it.

Comment: Thanks - as these posts may be used as  user references I want to create something shorter than 22 characters.  Is it bad form to use random string characters?  Can they be mapped to a UUID (for internal referencing purposes) and will they be unique to my application?

Comment: In that case you need to use SecureRandom (link above) to create a shorter string and store it separately in the database, checking for uniqueness and generating another one if there's a collision.  I have some applications where I do that using a "before_create" or "before_validation" callback to create the identifier.  For such tables I leave a standard numeric ID that my application uses internally.   You can override "to_param" to make it use your other key for urls.