# How do i properly choose URL ids when accessing UUID database?

Tags: api, url, amazon-dynamodb, uuid, url-shortener

I'm currently working on an API in AWS which is using a DynamoDB Table, which primary Key is an UUID like 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000.

So my GET Request would use this url: `example.com/users/123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000`, which to me is way too long and not user friendly.
Because of DynamoDB i cant use a counter either.
I researched a bit and of course theres [nanoid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid), but to be really unique it has to be still quite long.

How is stackoverflow solving this problem by using short numerical ids?
for example: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615900`

Ideally im looking for a solution, where i can have a url like `example.com/users/26615900`, while still referencing to DynamoDB and keeping its scalability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a incremental counter in dynamo, there are plenty of SO posts on how to make a counter for PKs.

You also have to evaluate why you are using a UUID as your Primary Key. Why not something more readable, with a secondary sort key to make it unique - if you are using a UUID because you only have a Partition Key and no Sort Key, then maybe dynamo isnt the right solution for your table needs. Dynamo works best and gives the most power when it is set up based on Access Patterns - you have this bit of information (your PK) and you need these types of documents/objects (your sks) so you can query based on that one PK and get all the possible data you would need from the different documents under the SKs.

If you are trying to do every single entry in your dynamo with a unique composite key you are forfeiting much of the power that a NoSQL like Dynamo brings, and you should consider if it is right for your product

Alternatives to UUIDs that can work - a Unix Timestamp with some other value (like as a username - first few characters of their name) prefixing or suffixing it is most of the time going to be functionally unique within your system. (if you do it right it will be vanishingly rare for two different people with the same combination of letters creating an account at the exact same millisecond for instance)

But you really need to consider your access patterns and what you plan to access based on that information you have. The combination of PK + SK makes a Composite Key and that composite key has to be unique - but that means you can have several PKS with the same value as long as the combination of that PK+SK is different.